# turtle.xcor()/.ycor() if-statement comparison doesn't return true when it should

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to do a comparison of the turtles position with the bounds of my box to make sure it's in bounds.

First I put the turtle at (0,0) and set playing to True with

```
t.goto(0,0)
playing = True
```

Then I start the while loop (everything beyond here is in this while loop)

```
while playing:
```

Then I do a movement

```
t.fd(10)
```

Then I do this comparison...

```
if t.xcor() < -200 or t.xcor() > 200 or t.ycor() < -200 or t.ycor() > 200:
  playing = False
```

My problem is that my turtle only ever moves once before exiting the loop - the loop only executes once before the exit condition is met. Is xcor()/ycor() not the best option here? Looking at the python docs on Turtle it seems like it should work. I'm lost here. Help?

Edit: printed t.xcor() before and after t.fd(10), I get 0 first and then -4.2345234e-15 (not sure if that means ^15 or ^-15).

Comment: Please post the whole program. The logic here seems fine. Something else is wrong.

Comment: I edited, does that clear things up?

Comment: Lim I'm confident that this is the problem. I've run everything up to this point and without it it runs indefinitely.

Comment: -4..e-15 is a negative number very close to 0 (-4... x 10^-15). What happens to ycor?

Comment: 10 even. The only thing I could think of was that it somehow meant ^15 so it was a very large number instead of practically 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by declaring variables

```
tx, ty = t.pos()
```

and then doing the comparison

```
if tx < -200 or tx > 200 or ty < -200 or ty > 200:
   playing = False
```

Still don't know why that was an issue.